# Component output at the touch of a button ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 buttons, when I click on one of them, the component will be displayed in the div info. How to make it so that no matter how many buttons we have (let's say we have 50 buttons) and 50 different components are displayed? It should be universal.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Donald from '/.Donald';
import John from '/.John';

class Names extends Component {
    state = {
      array:[
        {id:1,name:<Donald/>},
        {id:2,name:<John/>},
      ]
    };


   showComponent = (id,name) => {
    return this.state.array.map(() =>
      <button key={id}>{name}</button>
    )
   };

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="info">{this.name}}</div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={ () => this.showComponent(1) }>My name Donald</button>
          <button onClick={ () => this.showComponent(2)}>My name John</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Names;
```

Comment: Returning a component from a button click will not put it on the page, it won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding what components are used for. You should really never have 50 different components on a page.

Instead of having a component for Donald and John, Why don't you have a `<Person>` component, and pass the relevant data about the individual through it's props.

I know this might not actually be your real use case, but there is generally going to be a more reasonable solution then having so many different components.